# Adding a Class to a Shopware Theme Plugin

Tags: themes, shopware

We have a theme plugin which is encrypted with CodeIgniter. I only want to change the color of a button but the class does not exist. I assumed the theme pulled the button from the Bare or the Responsive Template. After searching for the button code I find it in the Bare ajax.checkout.tpl and add a class and even an inline style to the button. After clearing the Template cache, I still see no change. Am I wrong in thinking that the button is pulled from the Bare template file or have I simply missed a step?

Comment: Also you can study these documents: https://developers.shopware.com/designers-guide/theme-startup-guide/ 
and
https://en-community.shopware.com/Theme-Manager_detail_1837.html

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the theme-inhertance: https://developers.shopware.com/designers-guide/smarty/#template-inheritance

Create a new theme with "injectbeforeplugins = false" and add an all.less to your individual theme. In this all.less you can override the class with your own styles.

Changing files in a custom plugin or the standard themes is considered bad practise. Since the Bare-Theme is loaded before the plugins, the plugin will override all changes in the bare theme. You need to change this in your own theme with "injectbeforeplugins = false" as described in the documentation.